# SqlPackage cannot import permission 'EAES'

Tags: sql-server, sqlpackage

When I try to deploy an SQL Server Database using SqlPackage I get a strange error.

The call is:

```
SqlPackage.exe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:myDb.dacpac /TargetServerName:myServer /TargetDatabaseName:myDb /OverwriteFiles:True /Diagnostics:True
```

The error is:

> Microsoft.Data.Tools.Diagnostics.Tracer Error: 1 : Error detected when
>   reverse engineering the database. Severity:'Warning' Prefix:'' Error
>   Code:'0' Message:The permission 'EAES' was not recognized and was not
>   imported.  If this problem persists, contact customer support.
>   Microsoft.Data.Tools.Diagnostics.Tracer Error: 1 : Error detected when
>   reverse engineering the database. Severity:'Warning' Prefix:'' Error
>   Code:'0' Message:The permission 'EAES' was not recognized and was not
>   imported.  If this problem persists, contact customer support.
>   Microsoft.Data.Tools.Diagnostics.Tracer Error: 19 :
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServicesException: An error occurred during
>   deployment plan generation. Deployment cannot continue. Error
>   SQL72018: Permission could not be imported but one or more of these
>   objects exist in your source.
>        ---> Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.DeploymentFailedException:
>   Errors occurred while modeling the target database.  Deployment can
>   not continue.
>          at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeployment.ThrowIfErrors(String
>   message, ErrorManager errors, Object category)
>          at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentEndpointServer.OnLoad(ErrorManager
>   errors, DeploymentEngineContext context)
>          at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeployment.PrepareModels()
>          at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeployment.InitializePlanGeneratator()
>          at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeployment.CreateController(Action`1
>   msgHandler)
>          at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.CreateController(SqlDeployment
>   deploymentEngine, ErrorManager errorManager)
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>       Initializing deployment (Failed)
>       Microsoft.Data.Tools.Diagnostics.Tracer Information: 0 : SqlPackage completed

When I do a schema compare in Visual Studio Data Tools, only one column is changed, but no permissions. When I use SSMS to look for that permission 'EAES', I cannot find it.

This solution worked for a while without problems.

What is that permission 'EAES' or how can I make the SqlPackage execution succeed again?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Visual Studio. See https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32896864-grant-execute-any-external-script-not-recognised-b

It will work again if you revoke the permission to execute R scripts in SQL Server

```
REVOKE EXECUTE ANY EXTERNAL SCRIPT TO [myUser]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your SQLPackage.exe, my problem was solved when I did this.
I got this problem when I was trying to publish in a SQL Server 2019 database, got the latest version from it in https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-download?view=sql-server-ver15 and it worked like a charm.